# Display product price under the product image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I would like to display product varation price under image. I am using some code in my **`functions.php`** but not working please any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails','woocommerce_single_variation',30 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to:

Remove the **`woocommerce_template_single_price`** in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** hook:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 */
```

To add it in **`woocommerce_before_single_product_summary`** hook:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
 */
```

So your code will be:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails','woocommerce_template_single_price', 30 );
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you @Loic TheAztec. but on click varation price not changing means i want to change price on every click. I have different prices for each each combination

Comment: @coder - Sorry, but your question is not clear. **This is not really possible *(or very complicated to get it work, a real development…)*** as the dynamic price is related to `single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php` and is working with Existing JavaScript/Ajax wooCommerce events. But in the context of your question my answer is correct and working… So you will have to re-ask your question in another thread, but as this is really complicated (a real development), I don't think you will get a useful answer.